# Custom columns width with fluid grid susy

Tags: susy-sass, susy, susy-next

I would like to know if there is a way to change column width on susy but  using fluid layouts instead of static.

Answer (score 0):

Fluid in Susy means it will calculate the column width for you, if you want to set static column width, you should use math:static instead